# Does .NET's LINQ Keyword 'TAKE' short circuit?

Tags: .net, linq, take

Does the TAKE keyword used in a linq query cause the execution of that linq query to short circuit when evaluated or does that .Any method cause the short circuit?

```
value = (From DataRow In MyDataTable Where DataRow.Item("MyColumn").ToString = "Y" Take 1).Any
```

Comment: Both.  Take will take only the first 1 record, and then the any will short circuit as soon as it finds one that matches (but there is only a maximum of 1 because of the take).  You can safely remove the Take 1 and have the same performance.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the answer!

Comment: @RobertMcKee That should be an answer not comment...

Comment: I was thinking someone would come along and expand on it, but since they didn't, I'll make it an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Both. Take will take only the first 1 record, and then the any will short circuit as soon as it finds one that matches (but there is only a maximum of 1 because of the take). You can safely remove the Take 1 and have the same performance.

Answer (score 0):

The term *short-circuit* doesn't really apply here, because it is about [boolean evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation). See some examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9344369/861716). It doesn't apply because `Take` doesn't return a boolean.

What you probably mean to ask is: does `Take` execute if `Any` is the next method in line? Logically, `Take` could be skipped if `Any` is also executed, because `Any` also stops after having found the first match.

However, we're just looking at a couple of extension methods, called consecutively:

```
value = MyDataTable.AsEnumerable() _
       .Where(Function(DateRow) DataRow.Item("MyColumn").ToString = "Y") _
       .(Take(1)) _
       .Any()
```

So `Take` runs, and then whatever method happens to come next, in this case `Any`. How would `Take` know it doesn't need to run? This can easily be demonstrated if you build your own extension methods from the [source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,44b8532e11187695,references) and add trace statements.

Maybe an underlying question is, does it matter performance-wise? Well, it's two iterations (tops) vs. one, trying to prevent it would be a micro optimization.