# How to code a "if X or If Y AND Z" in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, boolean-logic

I'm trying to code something who could be say by "If X or if Y AND Z" but it looks like I made a mistake

```
if((machine.isUsed == false) || (if(this.whoUseIt.includes(Session.get("loggedUser")))&&(machine.isUsed))){
```

I need to do this test to avoid a code duplication. If you have a better idea I'm still opened to it.

Comment: In almost every language it will take this form `if (x || (y && z)) {` I don't use javascript but I'd assume it does too. Try removing the extra `if` in the middle

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw you are right, you can put an answer you were the first one. Then why I got so much down votes ?

Comment: @Jerome Ignore the "downvote"s. What does "downvote" add to the inquiry without relevant and meaningful description accompanying? The important part is getting answer to your Question

Comment: @guest271314 yes you are right but it still a bit annoying, anw I learned a lot of things with all the answers :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `!` rather than `== false` and removing the extra parentheses:

```
if (!machine.isUsed || (this.whoUseIt.includes(Session.get("loggedUser")) && machine.isUsed)) {
```

But `not A or (B and A)` can be simplified to `not A or B`:

```
if (!machine.isUsed || this.whoUseIt.includes(Session.get("loggedUser"))) {
```

It reads as: if the machine is not used or this is the user that is using it.

Comment: Hi, no I can't simplify because to test the  `this.whoUseIt.includes(Session.get("loggedUser"))` the `machine.isUsed` must be true

Comment: If `machine.isUsed` is true then `!machine.isUsed` is false and the value of  `this.whoUseIt.includes(Session.get("loggedUser"))` is then required. Testing if `machine.isUsed` is true is redundant if we have already tested that it is not false.

Comment: @Jerome [Short-circuit evaluation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9344369/1270789) also guarantees that the second expression will never be called if `isUsed` is false.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the input and now I'll review my code because I'm sure I have a lot of redundant test

Answer (score 0):

Remove `if()` within `if` condition

```
if (machine.isUsed == false 
  || this.whoUseIt.includes(Session.get("loggedUser")) 
  && machine.isUsed) {}
```

Comment: Please bracket (or indent as a bare minimum) as I for one have to stop and think which of `||` and `&&` has the higher precedence. Also, `!machine.isUsed` would be better, IMO.

Comment: @KenY-N Brackets are not necessary. Not sure what you mean by "better"?

Comment: @KenY-N, why do you have to think which of `||` or `&&` has precedence? It just as logical as multiplication having precedence over addition.

Comment: @trincot I know, and that's how I remember it, but I always do have to consciously think which it should be! Perhaps it is just me, but I always apply the "principle of least astonishment" to `||` and `&&`, although never to `+` and `*`...

Comment: I have more trouble with understanding code that is full of parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(x || (Y && Z)){...}
```

Should be fine.

You don't need to add another if inside if.

Answer (score 0):

`If X or if Y AND Z` => `If (X || (Y && Z))`

```
 if(
   (machine.isUsed == false) || 
   (this.whoUseIt.includes(Session.get("loggedUser")) && (machine.isUsed))
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(X || (Y && Z)){
    /* your logic
}
```

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, one should always add a explanation to it explaining why/how the problem is solved.