# Count the number of integers in an array divisible by a given query k

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, performance, optimization

In this problem I have a number of queries for which I have to output the count of `integers` in the `array` which is divisible by k(one of the queries).The `array` contains duplicate elements. I am trying to optimise the problem and my approach is given below :

Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
     int[] ar={2,4,6,9,11,34,654,23,32,54,76,21432,32543,435,43543,643,2646,4567,457654,75,754,7,567865,8765877,53,2};
     int query=sc.nextInt();
     int length=ar.length;
     int count=0;
     for (int i=0;i<query ;i++ ) {
        int x=sc.nextInt();
        for (int j=0;j<length ;j++ ) {
            if(ar[j]>x){
                if(ar[j]%x==0){
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Count:"+count);
     }
}
```

The above code gives the correct output, but the complexity is `O(query*length)` and what if the array size is much bigger,the program will `timeout`.

Can anyone help me optimize the problem?

Comment: You could separate your `ar` array into three smaller arrays: One with primes, one with small non-primes and one with large non-primes. For the primes, you don't have to check a modulo remainder. A number which is equal to a prime cannot be equal to another prime. Depending on the size of `x`, you can skip the small array numbers.

Comment: is this a problem from any coding platform like hackerank or leetcode? If yes, can you provide the link for the problem to verify the test cases?

Comment: Ok I will try that

Comment: @CodeHunter, it is a problem from the coding platform hackerearth, but it does not show any test case.

Comment: What's the maximum length of the array? and what's the maximum value of an element in that array?

Comment: @IslamHassan maximum size of the array is `10^5` and maximum value of an element in an array is `10^5' , also the maximum query  size is `10^5`

Comment: Why do you check `ar[j]>x`? If ar[j] is 0 or x it also divisible by x.

Comment: Ya, my bad for putting `ar[j]>x`. But still if I don't use `ar[j]>x` , it doesn't get optimised

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a precomputation step to build a divisors' table. For every element in the array calculate its divisors. You can calculate divisors of a number efficiently in `O(sqrt(V))` assuming `V` is the maximum value in the array. Building the full table will cost `O(n * sqrt(V))` which according to your constraints equals `100,000 * sqrt(100,000) =~ 32M` which shouldn't be a lot. Memory complexity would be the same.

Then you can answer your queries in `O(1)` by a lookup in the table.

You can check this [link](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-divisors-natural-number-set-1/) for how to generate divisors in `O(sqrt(V))`.

Comment: Okay , I will try that

Comment: Can you help me making the divisors table, like what data structure should I use to store the divisors

Comment: A hashset should be enough. Whenever you find a number that divides any number in the array insert it into a hashset. Later when you receive a query check that whether it's in the hashset or not.

Comment: There is just one problem, if suppose the array contains duplicate values the output of the query won't be correct

Comment: I applied your algorithm, and instead of `hashset` I used an `arraylist` since the array can contain duplicate elements but the time limit exceeded. The main problem here is that the `array` contains duplicate elements and even if I were to build a divisors' table for every query I have to get the frequency/count of the query in the `list` and for that the time limit exceeds.

Comment: You HAVE TO use a hashset, a lookup in an arraylist will take O(n) which will take long, while a lookup in a hashset takes O(1). It shouldn't matter if you have duplicate divisors or not, you only need to check if a divisor exists or not, you don't care how many times it exists. So instead of doing this check ```ar[j]%x==0```, you'll do ```hashset.contains(x)```.

Comment: I have specifed in my question that `I have to output the count of integers in the array which is divisible by k(one of the queries)`, so it will matter if I have duplicate divisors. Also, I have edited my question.

Comment: You can use a hashmap instead of a hashset and keep the count in it while calculating the divisors. The main idea is to use hashing whether it's a hashset or a hashmap won't affect the complexity.

Comment: Buiding a table of all multiples is much simpler and faster.

Answer (score 2):

> and maximum value of an element in an array is 10^5

This makes it trivial. Use `boolean[10001]` and mark all multiples of all queries. Then use it for testing the elements.

The new problem is how to mark all the multiples when there are many small queries. The worst case would be queries like `{1, 1, 1, ...}`, but duplicates can be trivial removed e.g., using a `HashSet`. Now the worst case is `{1, 2, 3, 4, ...}`, which needs `10001/1 + 10001/2 + 10001/3...` steps. You can do some special treatment for the smallest queries like removing multiples.

For example, when you look at all queries up to 10 and remove multiples among them, then the worst case is `{2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 12, 13, 14...}`, which should make the marking pretty fast. This step may not be needed at all.

Answer (score 1):

One optimization that you could do is to take advantage of [short-circuiting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9344305/what-is-short-circuiting-and-how-is-it-used-when-programming-in-java), and use one if statement (instead of two).

So change this:

```
if(ar[j]>x) {
  if(ar[j]%x==0) {
```

to this:

```
if(ar[j]>x && ar[j]%x==0) {
```

This will not affect the time complexity of your algorithm, but it will help [Branch Prediction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_predictor).

Comment: Ya, tried that but my main motive is to break the `O(query*length)` and optimise it.

Comment: It won't. The two snippets are equivalent and the compiler (JITc not javac) knows it.