# C Program Output Complexity

Tags: c

Could you please explain why the following program is giving such outputs?

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i=-3,j=1,k=0;
    int m;
    m=++i || ++j && ++k;
    printf("i= %d\nj=%d\nk=%d\nm=%d", i,j,k,m);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

i= -2
j=1
k=0
m=1

Comment: Were you expecting something different ? I suspect you're being teased by *boolean evaluation short-circuiting* (little google food there).

Comment: Essentially [What is short circuiting and how is it used when programming in Java? (duplicate)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9344305/what-is-short-circuiting-and-how-is-it-used-when-programming-in-java) for C

Comment: @WhozCraig Actually I am a novice. I don't know much about these types of calculations.

Comment: @Shuvomandol No matter what your skill level is, it would help if you can narrow down exactly what you find puzzling.  For example, you probably understand why `i` got incremented from `-3` to `-2`.  It's a waste of time if we have to explain that to you in our answers if you already know it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `++i` is essentially `true`, because it is not `0`, therefore the `||` other part will not be evaluated, since it does not matter at this point, the expression is `true`. Therefore `j` and `k` will not change. `true` is `1`, that is why `m` is `1`.

Comment: Could you please explain why ++i is essentially true here?

Comment: `++i` beame `-2`. In C everything which is not `0` considered `true`. So your expression is at this point `true || <other_expressions>`. Since `true` OR anything is `true` therefore the `<other_expressions>` evaluation is skipped (short circuit).

Comment: Also `&&` (like multiplication) has greater priority then `||` (like addition,) so `++i || (++j && ++k)`. If it would have been `(++i || ++j) && ++k` it would have incremented `k`.