# Boolean Operation Meaning in React Native

Tags: react-native, boolean-logic, boolean-operations

I'm typically a back-end programmer so to assist with some of the initial work i got a project that had a template project set up. I'm trying to understand some things as my first React Native Project and i can't seem to understand what this logic is saying for bgColor? :

```
const navbarStyles = [
      styles.navbar,
      bgColor && { backgroundColor: bgColor }
    ];
```

Any explanations or references that could help? Appreciate it!

Comment: bgColor && { backgroundColor: bgColor } will return null if bgColor is null, and return  { backgroundColor: bgColor } if bgColor is not null. it's just && operator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called short-circuiting and is a short-hand way of doing:

```
if (bgColor) { //implies bgColor != undefined (and also != null, != 0 etc)
    backgroundColor: bgColor
}
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you very much! I found this on short-circuiting: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9344305/what-is-short-circuiting-and-how-is-it-used-when-programming-in-java