# dropdownlist-selecteditems error

Tags: asp.net

i have 3 dropdownlist and 1 button.., when page load,its goes to last else part...if i select any one dropdown and click btn..its shows empty even if i have data in database... i think i made some mistake in selecteditem part...can u plz suggest some idea for this....

```
if (employee_name_ddl.SelectedItem.Text != "Select" & employee_paricularpro_ddl.SelectedItem.Text == "Select" & employee_status_ddl.SelectedItem.Text == "All Status")
            {
                ............
            }
            else if (employee_name_ddl.SelectedItem.Text == "Select" & employee_paricularpro_ddl.SelectedItem.Text != "Select" & employee_status_ddl.SelectedItem.Text == "All Status")
            {
                ............................
            }
            else if (employee_name_ddl.SelectedItem.Text == "Select" & employee_paricularpro_ddl.SelectedItem.Text == "Select" & employee_status_ddl.SelectedItem.Text != "All Status")
            {
               ............................
            }
            else if (employee_name_ddl.SelectedItem.Text != "Select" & employee_paricularpro_ddl.SelectedItem.Text != "Select" & employee_status_ddl.SelectedItem.Text == "All Status")
            {
                ...............................
            }
            else if (employee_name_ddl.SelectedItem.Text != "Select" & employee_paricularpro_ddl.SelectedItem.Text == "Select" & employee_status_ddl.SelectedItem.Text != "All Status")
            {
               ........................
            }
            else if (employee_name_ddl.SelectedItem.Text == "Select" & employee_paricularpro_ddl.SelectedItem.Text != "Select" & employee_status_ddl.SelectedItem.Text != "All Status")
            {
               ...................
            }
            else if (employee_name_ddl.SelectedItem.Text != "Select" & employee_paricularpro_ddl.SelectedItem.Text != "Select" & employee_status_ddl.SelectedItem.Text != "All Status")
            {
       .........................
            }
            else
            {
                ....................
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

The default for [`ListControl.SelectedItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.selecteditem.aspx) is `null`, hence you might get a `NullReferenceException` on the `Text` property somewhere when any `DropDownList` is not selected.

You're also using the bitwise comparison `&` instead of the correct logical `&&`.

Here's an example to show the difference of `&` and `&&`:

```
if(employee_name_ddl.SelectedItem != null && employee_name_ddl.SelectedItem.Text == "Select")
{
    // no exception whether or not employee_name_ddl.SelectedItem is null
}

if(employee_name_ddl.SelectedItem != null & employee_name_ddl.SelectedItem.Text == "Select")
{
    // exception when employee_name_ddl.SelectedItem is null,
    // because the second condition will be evaluated anyway
}
```

[What is the diffrence between & and && operators in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4163483/what-is-a-diffrence-between-and-operator-in-c-sharp)

Comment: hi @Tim Schmelter, thanks for replying me...shall i use      if(employee_name_ddl.SelectedItem != null & employee_name_ddl.SelectedItem == null)

Comment: @user1285783: I thought it would be self-explanatory. No, you should use `if(employee_name_ddl.SelectedItem != null && employee_name_ddl.SelectedItem.Text == "Select")` (the first approach with the comment "// no exception")

Comment: if i use && it will check both condition?