# Where and how to use && Operators

Tags: c#, xaml, winrt-xaml

I have this piece of code which i simplified from my app. It does what I  want but I know its not put in the most efficient way because I'm still having some trouble understanding the `&&` and `&` operators.

```
if (AgeInput.Text.Equals(""))
{
    Textblock1.Text = "✘";
}
else if (AgeInput.Text.All(Char.IsNumber)){
    Textblock1.Text = "✔";
    //DO-THIS-A
}
else
{
    Textblock1.Text = "✘";
}
```

I need it to make sure there is no white spaces in the string and to also check so its not empty and finally check if its a number, If it ticks all those requirements it will //DO-THIS-A

Whats the most efficient way to do this?

EDIT:
If somebody knows how to make a XAML textbox numerical only (so no whitespaces) that would be even better (only a single property or don't worry otherwise)

Comment: Premature optimizations won't help to much.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get a TextBox to only accept numeric input in WPF?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268552/how-do-i-get-a-textbox-to-only-accept-numeric-input-in-wpf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(AgeInput.Text) && AgeInput.Text.All(char.IsNumber))
    Textblock1.Text = "✔";
else
    Textblock1.Text = "✘";
```

`String.IsNullOrEmpty` returns true if the input is as stated: Null or Empty.

We Invert that with the "`!`", so that it returns true if it isn't empty.

Then we add the `&&` Operator to expand the if condition and ask if the text only contains numbers.

Also look here: [For a description of the difference between &, && and |, ||](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4163483/what-is-the-diffrence-between-and-operators-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Yes thankyou, I thought I had to use a ! operator somewhere but I did not know where to place it.

I knew about `String.IsNullOrEmpty` but didnt see a need to use it as `"" `worked either way

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure I understand your question, because && and & are for totally different uses.

```
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(AgeInput.Text))
{
    Textblock1.Text = "✘";
}
else if(Char.IsNumber(AgeInput.Text.All))
{
    Textblock1.Text = "✔";
}
```

The `&` is a binary operator and `&&` is a logical operator.

Comment: `&` is also a logical operator in C#; it is perfectly legal to use it on bools. The difference is that `&&` is *lazy* and `&` is *eager*. The lazy operator only evaluates the left hand side if necessary; the eager operator always evaluates both sides.

Comment: I had no idea about that, at all! Thanks.