# Why use & over &&?

Tags: comparison-operators, operands

I know what `&` and `|` does - it evaluates both sides (or all conditions if more than 2) - but I can't say I've used those two operators for a very long time, I always used `&&` and `||`.

e.g. `(a != null) & (a.length == 1)` would throw if we're checking the length of `a` after we know it's null, and obviously `(a != null) && (a.length == 1)` would just return false if `a` was null without the need to check if the length of `a` is 1. I also know there's a slight performance benefit to using `&&` and `||` if you have many conditions to check returning true/false at condition 2/100 is faster than evaluating all 100 knowing it's true/false at condition 2.

What situations would require the single `&`and `|` operands?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8418295/logical-vs-bitwise

Comment: Hope the first example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4163483/what-is-the-difference-between-and-operators-in-c-sharp) answers your question fully. Just try to use Google next time firstly

Comment: Which programming language is this? Please add a corresponding tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`&&` and `||` is the **logical** AND or OR between two predicates. This is why it could be more efficient as with logical AND or OR we can do [Short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

On the other side, `&` and `|` applies a **bitwise** AND or OR. This does not use Short-circuit evaluation. The use of this is generally less to do with the checking against predicates, and more to do with bit based operations such as [bit-masking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_(computing)).